# How to create image like ARKit face

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, arkit

How can generate an image of 3d Face using ARKit of iPhone X

For example [image]

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5491-ar-face-tracking-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: I have develop the code , but my question is how to create such image as shown above?
Is it possible to create an image from 3d Image

Comment: I don't think there is direct way to do this. what you can do is snapshot of arscnview

Comment: But if some one generate this image in ARKit example then there must be some rule to create it